# How to get the data from external file for drawing the graph in canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, canvas

```html
<html>
<head>
  <style>html{font-family:Verdana;}</style>
 
<script type="text/javascript">

var canvas ;
var context ;
var Val_max;
var Val_min;
var sections;
var xScale;
var yScale;
  // Values for the Data Plot, they can also be obtained from a external file
var Apple =  [100, 102, 87, , 100, 123, 100, 90, 87, 91, 93, 88];
var Samsung = [30, 50, 70, 80, 90, 100, 95, 91, 85, 92, 99, 130];
var Nokia =   [20, -10, -20, -25, -40, 5, 10, 28, 30, 43, 65, 80];

function init() {
  // set these values for your data 
 sections = 12;
 Val_max = 130;
 Val_min = -40;
 var stepSize = 10;
 var columnSize = 50;
 var rowSize = 50;
 var margin = 10;
 var xAxis = [" ", "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"] 
  //
  
 canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
 context = canvas.getContext("2d");
 context.fillStyle = "#0099ff"
 context.font = "20 pt Verdana"
 
 yScale = (canvas.height - columnSize - margin) / (Val_max - Val_min);
 xScale = (canvas.width - rowSize) / sections;
 
 context.strokeStyle="#009933"; // color of grid lines
 context.beginPath();
  // print Parameters on X axis, and grid lines on the graph
 for (i=1;i<=sections;i++) {
  var x = i * xScale;
  context.fillText(xAxis[i], x,columnSize - margin);
  context.moveTo(x, columnSize);
  context.lineTo(x, canvas.height - margin);
 }
  // print row header and draw horizontal grid lines
 var count =  0;
 for (scale=Val_max;scale>=Val_min;scale = scale - stepSize) {
  var y = columnSize + (yScale * count * stepSize); 
  context.fillText(scale, margin,y + margin);
  context.moveTo(rowSize,y)
  context.lineTo(canvas.width,y)
  count++;
 }
 context.stroke();
 
 context.translate(rowSize,canvas.height + Val_min * yScale);
 context.scale(1,-1 * yScale);
 
  // Color of each dataplot items
  
 context.strokeStyle="#FF0066";
 plotData(Apple);
 context.strokeStyle="#9933FF";
 plotData(Samsung);
 context.strokeStyle="#000";
 plotData(Nokia);
}

function plotData(dataSet) {
 context.beginPath();
 context.moveTo(0, dataSet[0]);
 for (i=1;i<sections;i++) {
  context.lineTo(i * xScale, dataSet[i]);
 }
 context.stroke();
}

</script>
</head>

<body onLoad="init()">
<div align="center">
<h2>Monthly Profits of Companies(in million $)</h2>

<canvas id="canvas" height="400" width="650">
</canvas>
<br>
 <!--Legends for Dataplot -->
<span style="color:#FF0066"> Apple </span>  
<span style="color:#9933FF"> Samsung</span>  
<span style="color:#000"> Nokia </span>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Hi,
I need to plot a simple linear graph. 
I am not allowed to use any libraries and frameworks and API. I have tried this. 
But I need to plot a graph with the data from external json file. 
How can get the data from external file? Can anyone please help me to do that. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this helps

```
function loadJSON(callback) {
    var xobj = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xobj.overrideMimeType("application/json");
    xobj.open('GET', 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/1igag', true);
    xobj.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xobj.readyState == 4 && xobj.status == "200") {
            callback(xobj.responseText);
        }
    }
    xobj.send(null);
}
```

```js
  var Apple = [];
  var Samsung = [];
  var Nokia = [];

function loadJSON(callback) {
    var xobj = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xobj.overrideMimeType("application/json");
    xobj.open('GET', 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/1igag', true);
    xobj.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xobj.readyState == 4 && xobj.status == "200") {
            callback(xobj.responseText);
        }
    }
    xobj.send(null);

}
loadJSON(function(response) {
  var response;
  var field=JSON.parse(response);
  for (var i = 0; i < field.length; i++) {
        Apple.push(field[i].xxx);
        Samsung.push((field[i].xxx)+10);
        Nokia.push((field[i].xxx)-30);
      }
       sections = 12;
 Val_max = 130;
 Val_min = -40;
 var stepSize = 10;
 var columnSize = 50;
 var rowSize = 50;
 var margin = 10;
 var xAxis = [" ", "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"] 
  //
  
 canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
 context = canvas.getContext("2d");
 context.fillStyle = "#0099ff"
 context.font = "20 pt Verdana"
 
 yScale = (canvas.height - columnSize - margin) / (Val_max - Val_min);
 xScale = (canvas.width - rowSize) / sections;
 
 context.strokeStyle="#009933"; // color of grid lines
 context.beginPath();
  // print Parameters on X axis, and grid lines on the graph
 for (i=1;i<=sections;i++) {
  var x = i * xScale;
  context.fillText(xAxis[i], x,columnSize - margin);
  context.moveTo(x, columnSize);
  context.lineTo(x, canvas.height - margin);
 }
  // print row header and draw horizontal grid lines
 var count =  0;
 for (scale=Val_max;scale>=Val_min;scale = scale - stepSize) {
  var y = columnSize + (yScale * count * stepSize); 
  context.fillText(scale, margin,y + margin);
  context.moveTo(rowSize,y)
  context.lineTo(canvas.width,y)
  count++;
 }
 context.stroke();
 
 context.translate(rowSize,canvas.height + Val_min * yScale);
 context.scale(1,-1 * yScale);
 
  // Color of each dataplot items
  
 context.strokeStyle="#FF0066";
 plotData(Apple);
 context.strokeStyle="#9933FF";
 plotData(Samsung);
  context.strokeStyle="#000";
 plotData(Nokia);

function plotData(dataSet) {
 context.beginPath();
 context.moveTo(0, dataSet[0]);
 for (i=1;i<sections;i++) {
  context.lineTo(i * xScale, dataSet[i]);
 }
 context.stroke();
}
    });
```

```html
<body>
<div align="center">
<h2>Monthly Profits of Companies(in million $)</h2>

<canvas id="canvas" height="400" width="650">
</canvas>
<br>
 <!--Legends for Dataplot -->
<span style="color:#FF0066"> Apple </span>  
<span style="color:#9933FF"> Samsung</span>  
<span style="color:#000"> Nokia </span>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: If possible can you please tell me..I need to get the data for both x axis and y axis from json api. Like if I am plotting the graph for apple vs samsung..How can I do that?

Comment: sure,you should create json with x and y axis value.Here loadJSON function will return json data as object,so you can easily plote accordingly.i think its easy for you to plote once its generate as object.